# WordPress Gravity Forms Entries Page Filter

Tags: php, wordpress, gravity-forms-plugin

We're attempting to filter the Gravity Forms *Entries* list on a particular users' website. We've got granular permission levels that have already been defined, but I only want the following to appear and I'm struggling with the logic.

Here, we need User1 if they belong to ChapterName to only display the entries with the *field* matching "chapter" from Gravity Forms.

I haven't found any functions or anything to even remotely assist with this. If anyone has any ideas on how to approach this, it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: what did you try so far?any coding?

Comment: `    add_filter( 'gform_search_criteria_entry_list', 'override_search_criteria' );
    function override_search_criteria( $search_criteria ) {
       
        $user_id = get_current_user_id();
        $key = 'chapter';
        $single = true;
        $chapter = get_user_meta( $user_id, $key, $single ); 

            $search_criteria['field_filters'][] = array( 'key' => '8', 'operator' => 'is', 'value' => $chapter );`